# VS2015 Extension Manager not reporting update for MSI-intalled extension

Tags: visual-studio, windows-installer, upgrade

I've written [a Visual Studio extension](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/2d5de770-50e9-4dcf-87e9-ea1ed1b43b68) which installs using an MSI. The install puts a `extension.vsixmanifest` file in the right place, and the extension appears in the Extension Manager as expected:

[image: Extension Manager details]

The problem is, when I publish a new version on the Visual Studio Gallery, the Extension Manager does not report it. I add the new version by creating a new installer and editing the existing page. Each new installer has a new ProductCode, PackageCode and ProductVersion (I update the MSI setup project and the version number in the included extension.vsixmanifest), but the same UpgradeCode; an example 'upgrade' commit can be found on GitHub [here](https://github.com/agileobjects/ReadableExpressions/commit/f33d94b63db24f1c1ec88ed0f607c888c2e0bd88).

The issue appears to be that when Visual Studio Extension Manager queries [the extensions service](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/Services/VStudio/Extension.svc) for the latest version of my extension, it returns a blank string - the same result as if you query with an invalid extension identifier:

[image: Service query results]

The two extensions successfully queried in the example are the [NuGet client tools](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/5d345edc-2e2d-4a9c-b73b-d53956dc458d) for VS2015 and the [SQL Server Compact/SQLite Toolbox](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/0e313dfd-be80-4afb-b5e9-6e74d369f7a1?SRC=Home).

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OhhhhhhKAY. I've solved this, and it turned out to be a problem with the Visual Studio Gallery page editor.

When you add an extension, you're shown a [VSIX ID](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/quanto/2009/05/26/what-is-a-vsix/) box:

[image: The VSIX ID box]

When you *edit* an extension (I'm using Chrome), that box has disappeared!

[image: No VSIX ID box]

It's still in the DOM, but it's hidden from view. Because of this, I never entered my extension's VSIX ID into the form, it didn't have a value associated with it, and the extensions service therefore didn't return a version number for that ID. The Extension Manager uses the extensions service to find out the latest versions of installed extensions, so it wasn't reporting new versions of mine.

The VSIX ID box reappears if you deselect then reselect one of the extension's supported Visual Studio versions, so I've been able to assign the ID that way. The service now returns a version number, and the Extension Manager therefore shows available updates:

[image: Update available!]

Answer (score 0):

Probably you may need to raise ProductVersion as well and mind correct version conditions in Upgrade Table in installer project. If this will not help try investigating this issue installing with full verbose log (msiexec /i installer.msi /l*v logfile.log) this may give some clues. The worst case you may want to add an entry to RemoveFiles table to delete this file (during install before deploying your file) but that sounds nasty and i would prefer  to avoid it.

Comment: Thanks for the ideas :) I am updating the ProductVersion (I've updated my question to reflect this) and I think the installer Upgrade Table is ok - it removes previous versions of itself during the install as it should. The problem is the Visual Studio Gallery not reporting an updated version.

Comment: Hm, i guess visual studio generates some configuration in configfiles or registry which occurs only first time file spotted. You may try to make a system snapshot before VS adds this plugin first time and see what changes it does.

Comment: Msi version do not support 4 digit format 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370859(v=vs.85).aspx
it just ignores everything that is after 3rd dot

Comment: Yep! The installer has a 3-digit version number. The extension currently has a 4-digit version but it previously had a 3-digit one and that didn't work either :/

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is a problem with your installer configuration, assuming your installer does, in fact, upgrade your product. If I understand your question correctly, this is an issue with Extension Manager.

Have you tried removing the trailing `.0` from your new version string? There might be an poor/unexpected comparison result when comparing a 3-dot version to a 4-dot version.

You could also try doing a more extreme version number change (upping the major version) to see if Extension Manager picks that up.

Comment: The example commit I linked is the first time I used a 4-digit version - previous 3-digit to 3-digit upgrades didn't show up, and I've now tried a 4-digit to 4-digit and that isn't showing up either. I tried updating the major version number and that wasn't shown either. Hmmmmmm...

Comment: One thing I've seen is that the [github extension](https://github.com/github/VisualStudio) has the vsix guid in both the  vsixmanifest file (VisualStudio/src/GitHub.VisualStudio/source.extension.vsixmanifest)  and the installer ProductInfo.wxi (VisualStudio/src/MsiInstaller/ProductInfo.wxi) file. Maybe your installer (vdproj) needs to have the same?

Comment: The VSIX ID variable defined in their ProductInfo.wxi is used for the ID of a Fragment element in the main Product.wxi - I don't think vdproj has an equivalent to that. The WIX version looks to also have a ProductCode and an UpgradeCode, the same as the vdproj.

Comment: So, to narrow the scope, is the Visual Studio Gallery not showing the new version (ex: I go to the page, I don't have the extension installed, it shows the old version) **OR** I already have the extension, the Gallery page has the updated version, but my extension manager does not recognize the upgrade as available?

Comment: The latter - the gallery website correctly updates to the latest version, but the Extension Manager does not report the available upgrade when you have an older version installed. I'll update my question with more details. Thanks :)